# Using a Variable to Copy Files From One Location to Multiple Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, copy, startup

So i have a file that i want to transfer from one location to multiple computers on my network using powershell, this is what i have so far.

```
robocopy "\\PTFGW-061403573\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" 
"\\$onlineComputers\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /mir /r:1 /o:0
```

when i run it it says the location is not found, and i can confirm that the variable holds all of the online computers within it. any ideas?

Comment: RoboCopy, according to the documentation, does not support multiple computer names in the destination. You can accomplish this using Copy-Item in a ForEach loop of $onlineComputers.

Comment: my knowledge of powershell is rather limited, how would i go about doing that in a working manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zizzay,

Here's some code that should do what you want. It puts the copy-item command in a TRY/Catch construct to catch and report any errors in the copying process. I assumed that the last item on your source (Startup) is a folder, thus the need for the Recurse argument in the $CIArgs. If it is not a folder remove the Recurse line. I also broke up your paths to cut down on repetition and make things easier to change. Note: I tested this on a Peer-to-Peer LAN, should work on a Domain based LAN.

```
$onlineComputers = "Computer1","ComputerN"
$FSBase = "C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"

$OnlineComputers  | 
   ForEach-Object {

 Try {
        $CIArgs = 
          @{Path        = "\\PTFGW-061403573\$FSBase"
            Destination = "\\$_.\$FSBase\Startup"
            Force       = $True
            Recurse     = $True
            ErrorAction = 'Stop'}
        Copy-Item @CIArgs
       }
       Catch {
             Write-Host @"
Could not write to: $_.
"@
       } #End Catch

} #End ForEach...
```

HTH

Comment: i keep getting an error saying that this variable is null.

    $($FilesToCopy[$fc])

Comment: Zizzay, sorry about that I didn't test against error case, I copied the the code from a program of mine and didn't do enough editing. I've fixed the code above. You may wish to edit the error message further to meet your needs. HTH

Comment: okay im sorry to keep prying but for some reason i keep getting an error saying that the network location is not found, im not sure what is causing that, but when i try to run it i take out the first line that you put in bc it replaces the variable i already filled with my various computers on my network. also i tried with and without the G$ in the file path only replacing it with C$ bc it matched my file path. any ideas on why it wont work properly on my side? im stumped.

Comment: Zizzay, do you know how to use the debugger in PowerShell_ISE? If you open the program in the ISE you can place your cursor on the  Copy-Item command and press F9. This will setup a break point, your program will stop every time you reach this command. Run your program. When it stops you can hover your cursor over $CIArgs variable and see how the items are expanding. Or you can use the CMD window to print the variable $CIArgs or individual values, e.g. $CIArgs.Path, etc. This will let you see if things are getting interpreted correctly. HTH

Comment: im pretty sure that the loop doesnt call each individual computer in their file path, could that be a problem with the way i set up my variable? my variable essentially pings each computer on the network and compiles the successfully pinged computers into an array. any further ideas on why it may not work on my end. i wasnt able to get the debugger to work but through testing iv gotten some ideas like that.

Comment: The code will call each computer in the $onlineComputers variable.  Without being able to see what substitutions are to determine the final paths it's hard to tell what  the problem is.

Comment: i figured out what my issue was after all of this, i needed a '.name' after my '$onlineComputers' variable so that each individual computer name was recognized. thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$onlineComputers = "Computer1","ComputerN"
$onlineComputers | Foreach {
 & robocopy.exe --% "\\PTFGW-061403573\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" 
"\\$($_)\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /mir /r:1 /o:0
}
```

You need to do a foreach on each item of the collection and specify $onlineComputers as an array. And added the stop parsing (--%) symbol to run the command more correctly. That's optional, and for safety.

Comment: when i run it i get this error.     At line:4 char:73
+ ... \ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /mir /r:1 ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:4 char:73
+ ... ogramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /mir /r:1 /o ...
+                                                               ~~~
Unexpected token 'mir' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException